# feedback like functionality using nested ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

I have been trying to achieve feedback like functionality using json data such that when I click on any  star all the stars in the current row get selected(their css change). 
Just like we normally see in the 5 star feedback.
I am currently struggle with the following code, can anyone help?

```
$scope.itemClicked = function (status, job) {
   if (status.isActive) {
     status.isActive = false;
   } else {
     angular.forEach(job.statuscollection, function(status) {
       status.isActive = false;
    });
    status.isActive = true;
   }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VA1XWWrG3pghEcWli06F?p=info

the current code allows me to select a specific item in the row, all I want is to change the css of all the Preceeding items in the row along with the current item.

any help would be really appreciated.

thanks

Comment: I have checked your plunkr code and I see no functioning there

Comment: Find the index of the clicked status in the array, and make all the status until this index active.

Comment: @JBNizet i have been trying it and i had no success with it. can you please provide me a better example with code. thanks

Comment: Post your best attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are actually looking for but I think you can achieve the functionality by using loop limit  with the parent index. Here's an example of code demonstration.

```
 <div ng-repeat="fb in feedback" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
    {{fb.question}}

     <br/>
     <span style="margin-left:10px" ng-repeat="star in fb.stars"
     ng-init="innerIndex = $index">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{ 'btn-info': star.isActive === true}" ng-click="itemClicked(star, fb)"> {{star.icon}} </button>
     </span>

     <br/><br/>
</div>


  $scope.itemClicked = function (outer, inner) {

         /* changing disabling all the items first */
          for(var loop = 0; loop < outer.stars.length; loop++){
             outer.stars[loop].isActive = false;
          }


        for(var loop = 0; loop < outer.stars.length; loop++){
          if(outer.stars[loop] !== inner )
            outer.stars[loop].isActive = true;
            else
             break;
        }

          inner.isActive = true;
      }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/1R9tqXM0yinvBQxfKNgD?p=preview

You can replace the buttons with your star icons. Hope this helps.

Comment: have also used external .json file to fetch json object from. cheers